# How to use parameterized test cases?

Tags: c++, c++11, googletest

I'm trying to use parameterized tests with a class that takes a POD as parameter. I've sort of reached this stage:

```
struct TestParameters : public ::testing::TestWithParam<parameters> {
  parameters params;

  virtual void SetUp() {
    params.username = "username";
    params.host = "192.168.0.254";
  }
};

TEST_P(TestParameters, connect) {
  std::error_code ec;
  std::unique_ptr<connection> connection = make_connection(GetParam(), ec);
  ASSERT_FALSE(ec);
  ec = connection->connect();
  ASSERT_FALSE(ec);
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(postgresql_tcp, connection, ::testing::Values());
```

My question is, how to pass the values I need in `parameters` via `INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P` and how to I pass a valid instance of `parameters` to `make_connection()`?

Comment: Doesn't [the documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#how-to-write-value-parameterized-tests) explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should be doing something along the lines of

```
INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(postgresql_tcp, connect,
                        ::testing::Values(parameters{"username", "192.168.0.254"}
                                      //, parameters{ other params here }
                                          ));
```

Or you could declare a `std::vector<parameters>` as a global somewhere that you dynamically could compute, and then pass iterators of that vector to `::testing::Values()`

Also, note you wouldn't need the member `params` in your fixture class, since the parameter is going to be fed automatically by Google Test through `GetParam()`

Comment: I don't want to create a constructor for my POD. Is it possible to create the object in place?

Comment: This is what the aggregate construction does in my example.
Assuming your type is defined as this:
`struct parameters {
    std::string username;
    std::string host;
};`
You can simply construct an instance by writing `parameters{"username", "192.168.0.254"}`

Comment: cf [this cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)

Comment: I can get aggregate initialisers to work in general, just not on Google test.

Comment: I just tried it on a simple example, and it works for me. What compiler are you using? Have you passed any flag to it to enable at least C++11 in your test project? What is the actual error message?

Comment: I passed -std=c++11. I'm on the latest Apple Clang. The error is "No matching constructor for initialization of 'parameters'"